# JSON pipeline in Python doesn't create any output file?

Tags: python, export, lidar, las, pdal

I have ground LiDAR point cloud with some noise points. I would like to use `filter.statistics` in PDAL (in Python 3.6) using JSON pipeline to filter the noise out.

```
json = """
{
  "pipeline":[
    "/9A-1B_subset15m.las",
    {
      "type":"filters.outlier",
      "method":"statistical",
      "mean_k":12,
      "multiplier":2.2
    },
    "/9A-1B_subset15m_c.las"
  ]
} """ 

import pdal
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json)
pipeline.validate()
```

The code runs without error but doesn't create any file. I wonder if anyone can help solving this?

Comment: Thanks @AndreSilva, the same problem. The code is running, but no output file.

Comment: I am using OSGeo Shell (https://pdal.io/workshop/osgeo4w.html) to run pdal and pipeline without problem. But, I am curious about why I cannot run the code above in Python.

Comment: @AndreSilva, PDAL 1.7.2 version

Comment: That absolute path is unlikely to work in windows.

Comment: PDAL uses the path given to try to open the file. There is no / path on windows AFAIK (which is where the pipeline tries to both read and write).

Answer (score 1):

I got answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690970/extracting-points-in-ground-lidar-using-python). After adding `pipeline.execute()`, now the code is running and creating exactly the same output as original one (not filtering out the noise). As this code is for airborne lidar, now I think I need to try different parameters to make a code remove the noise in ground lidar.

Comment: You can accept your own answer with the checkbox